# How to Model Data Where the Y-Axis = Percentage

Tags: graphing-functions, percentages, data-analysis

I have a situation where I have a bunch of values, and the percentage of each value occurring.  The values are ratios of one type of object to another type of object showing up at an event.  I found these ratios and the percentage of each occurring by running a computer simulation a couple thousand times.

I'm looking for the best way to visually model this on a graph.  I considered a simple X by Y graph, where the values are the X-axis and the percentage of each value occurring is the Y-axis.

If I were to do this, would it be correct to connect the points?  The problem I see with this is that each infinitesimal point on the line would have its own percentage of occurring, and this would lead to an infinite sum of percentage values (when the sum should only be 100).

If this is wrong to do, would it be better to just leave the dots unconnected?  Or am I looking at this the wrong way?  Would something like a bar graph be better suited for this situation?

Comment: Is there only a finite and equidistant amount of ratios that can actually occur? Or did you [bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) the data? Please [edit] your question to clarify. While you are at it, please also incorporate the information that you left in a comment under the answer.

Comment: There are far more ratios that were possible than what was given by the simulation.  The max number of objects from "Canada" was 30,000 and the max number of objects from "America" was 300,000.  Obviously the number of possible ratios from these two values exceeds what could have been outputted by my simulation that ran for only 3650 iterations.  Because of this, I'm planning on binning the data - for example, one group would include the ratios from 1.9 to 1.95, and another would include 1.95 to 2.0.  Would making each of these groups a separate bar in a bar graph make sense?

Comment: Please [edit] all the relevant information into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for connecting the points is to help estimating the $y$ value for $x$ values between the points.  As your $x$ values are discrete there is no reason for this, so a bar graph is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What if there is some pattern to the x-values though.  Example:  Most of the x-values given by the simulation are at 1.9, and then a roughly even number of x-values are given at 1.8 and 2.0.  The number of x-values at 1.7 and 2.1 are also around the same, and so forth.  Should the points still be treated as discrete, and modeled with a bar graph?

Comment: I thought your $x$ values were type of object and the $y$ values were percentage of that type.

Comment: No, the x values were the ratio of one type of object versus another type of object showing up at an event.  For example, ratio of Canadians vs Americans at a football game.  The y-value is the percentage of a certain ratio happening.  One point on the graph could have an x value of 1.9, and a y value of 20.  This would mean there is a 20% chance the ratio of Canadians to Americans at the event is 1.9.  Since my graph is based on probabilities, I wasn't sure if a normal graph with points connected by a line would be appropriate.

Comment: *The reason for connecting the points is to help estimating the $y$ value for $x$ values between the points.* – That is rarely ever done. The main reason to connect points is to enhance readability as it makes it easier to visually capture the behaviour of the data.

Comment: Is your $20\%$ the chance that the ratio is $1.9$ exactly (unlikely), $1.9 \pm 0.05$, or $\ge 1.9?$  In the $\ge 1.9$ case I would connect them as the lines will approximately follow the cdf.  In the $1.9 \pm 0.05$  case I would leave them unconnected.

Comment: @Ross Millikan The 20% is more like 1.9 +\- 0.02 or 1.9 +\- 0.015.  The 20% is just an experimental value provided by the simulation running a few thousand trials.  I'm just unsure about whether a connected graph with percentages is a bad idea.  Is it okay if the total sum of percentages for all the points exceeds 100?  Because if I draw a line then there will be an infinite number of points on it, causing the sum of all said points' percentage values to be infinite.

Comment: You should know the bin width because it comes from half the distance to each neighboring bin.  The widths are rather arbitrary, because you could double it and the percentage would jump to $40\%$  Often you plot the number per $0.01$ in ratio or something like that.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Sounds good, I'll probably do that then.  I was thinking about it, and maybe a pie chart would be a better idea than a bar graph?  Since if each pin is per 0.01, there will be too many bars in a bar graph.